# SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter and wssecurity

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cxf, ws-security

I have been experimenting with the various Java web service stacks (CXF, Metro and Spring-WS), and have come to the conclusion that none of them beat the simplicity of Spring's SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter, especially as the application is already built completely on a Spring stack. I had two concerns though, performance of the RI's built-in server in production, and security. I have found two alternatives to the first problem - a custom multi-threaded executor or replacing it entirely with Jetty.

Which brings me to my question. Does anyone know if it is at all possible to add some simple usernametoken authentication via ws-security transparently when exposing the services? Any suggestions that don't require changing the service interface itself (annotations, xml configuration, handler chains, etc) are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a web service security policy to your wsdl:

```
<sp:TransportToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpsToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:HttpsToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
```

Found some documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13713/transport.htm).